# Transfer Photos from Mac to Android Device

Tags: macbook-pro, android

How can I transfer photos from Mac(including iPhoto) into Android phone? When I connect my android phone to Mac via USB, iPhoto can recognize it, but I can only find the import new photo button, then where is the export photo to android phone button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Android phone in Finder, as it shows as just another USB device. Drag photos from iPhoto to the Android device in Finder.

Answer (score -1):

You can not use USB cable and still manage to transfer photos from Mac to Android device, if you use [AirMore](http://airmore.com/android-photos-to-mac.html), AirDrop or Dropbox to help you.